# odoo 11 indexed by google on port 8069

Tags: apache, odoo-11

I have odoo11 web server under reverse proxy with apache tomcat. to secure connection I've also enabled the https protocol with trusted SSL certificate.

all is working fine, if user connect to http://example.com is redirected to https://example.com.

The issue is with the standard odoo port, google spider indexed the example.com:8069, so if the user click on google search result will bypass tomcat, connecting directly to the odoo web server on insicure connection.

How can I avoid this? I tryied to redirect traffic from apache, but the server can't listen on port 8069... beacause it is already in use, also I could change the default odoo port, and keep apache listening on 8069, but google could always index the new port assigned to odoo... is there any configuration in odoo to avoid this behavior?

(I've also submitted sitemap.xml to google search console, I'm waiting to verify if this will take the desired effect)

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't have port 8069 opened in your firewall,

it shouldn't be accessible directly over the internet

you should use something like iptables to block port 8069 from outside access